Why is this localization thin?
I am studying this paper by Malkiewich and Ponto. I am unsure about one claim.
Let $\Delta$ be the augmented simplex category. Denote by $\mathfrak{J}$ the wide subcategory of $\Delta$ consisting of injective maps. On page 12 it is claimed:

Let $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ be the localization where every map is map invertible. Note that $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ has an initial object (the empty set), so it is an abstract clique.

An abstract clique is defined as a thin, connected groupoid.
The localization $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ is a groupoid by definition. $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ is connected because $\mathfrak{J}$ is.
But why is the localization $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ thin? What does it have to do with $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ having an initial object?
I am thinking that the localization $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ cannot be thin because $\mathfrak{J}$ already isn't and $\mathfrak{J}[\mathfrak{J}^{-1}]$ is obtained from $\mathfrak{J}$ by adding morphisms.

If $C$ is a groupoid with an initial object $\emptyset$, then for any arrows $f, g : x \to y$ in $C$, initiality gives an isomorphism $i : \emptyset \to x$.  Since $\emptyset$ is initial, we have that $fi = gi$, so $f = g$.
